# Elastic fuzziness query

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "default_field": "searchText",
            "query": "rob",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the mapping for field searchText

```
          "searchText" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
```

The search query is not returning any documents that has the value bob as part of the searchText. Do I have to update the query in a different way for fuzziness

Comment: I think this way apply [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `~` [operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-fuzziness) to have fuzzy searching in query_string:

```
POST test_fuzzy/_doc
{
  "searchText": "bob"
}

GET test_fuzzy/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "default_field": "searchText",
            "query": "rob~"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use a match query with "fuzziness": "AUTO"

```
GET test_fuzzy/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "searchText": {
              "query": "rob",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```